# How to Mock this concept

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, moq

```
class Test : ITest
{
   public string MyValue { get; }
   public string Detail {get; set;}
}
```

I want to Mock the method MyValue in this way

```
Test myTest = new Test() { Detail = "My Test" };
MockRepository repositoryTest = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
Mock<Test> mockTest = repositoryTest.Create(myTest);

mockTest.Setup(t => t.MyValue).Returns("Some text");
return myTest;
```

N.B. this code does not work, is only for understanding what I want.

Other way how can I mock an instance of an existing object? I use Google Moq.

Comment: What is the problem? If you call `myTest.Object.MyValue` you will get `Some Text` I think (from the top of my head)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be mocking on the interface, not the implementing class.

Use `Mock<T>.Get(T)` to get the `Mock<T>` from your `T`:

```
ITest test = new Mock<ITest>().Object;
Mock<ITest> mockTest = Mock<ITest>.Get(test);
```

---

**EDIT:** You can stub out properties using the `Moq.Stub` namespace. Take a look at this page: http://blog.theagileworkshop.com/2009/03/24/stubs-in-moq/

Comment: Ok but how to use Mock<ITest>().Object like an instance of Test object. Ex. if I want to set Detail value?

Comment: @Francis: Are you calling the property setter (i.e., specifically saying `myTestObject.Detail = someValue`) or are you merely calling the getter in the code you're testing? If you're just accessing the property in your code under test, simply use `mockTest.SetupGet(mock => mock.Detail).Returns(someValue)` in the unit test.

Comment: I only want to mock the property MyValue the property Detail must return is own value;

Comment: I updated my answer with a link that refers to `Moq.Stub`. That might help you out.

Comment: I want to create a collection of Test object, and for each Test object I want to Mock the MyValue property. What I want to do is My class is a domain class with a localisation mechanism for language. What I want is to create a collection of my domain classe with a bypass for the localisation mechanism.

Comment: Have you tried using `Mock<T>.Stub` yet? You should be able to stub a property so that it behaves like a normal property, and then mock your `MyValue` using `Mock<T>.Setup().Returns` like normal.